# Javascript associative comparison

Tags: javascript

In other programming languages such as Mathematica or Python, it is possible to do associative comparisons.

However in JavaScript, the following statement evaluates to true.

```
var a = 9, 
b = 5,
c = 1; 

if(a < b < c)
{
    alert(":/");
}
```

Can you explain why this is the case?

Thanks

Comment: You want us to explain why JavaScript isn't Mathematica or Python?

Comment: Think. In Javascript what does `a < b` give you?

Comment: @LeeTaylor I understand that, but 9 is not less than 5.

Comment: `9 < 5` is `false`, which converted as integer is `0` and `0 < 1` is true.

Comment: @FlorianGl Why put as comment what's already in an answer ?

Comment: @LouisEvans - Your comment proves (proved?) that you didn't understand what a<b gives you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a < b < c
```

is

```
(a < b) < c
```

which is either

```
true < c
```

or

```
false < c
```

which, due to conversion, is equivalent to

```
1 < c
```

or

```
0 < c
```

From [the MDN on comparison operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Summary) :

> If either operand is a number or a boolean, the operands are converted to numbers if possible

What you want is

```
if (a < b && b < c)
```

which is

```
if ( (a < b) && (b < c) )
```